# NSUserDefault BoolKey Not Saved Getting Reset After Closed App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use for launch my app below codes but in some devices nsuserdefaults not saved.When i terminated app from home button and again open,it starts as if nsuserdefaults not saved!

```
  NSUserDefaults *pref=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([pref boolForKey:@"islogin"])
{


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UITabBarController * tabbar = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"];


    tabbar.selectedIndex = 2;
    self.window.rootViewController = tabbar;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}else{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"register"];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Code moved from comment:

```
[pref setObject:[response valueForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"user_id"];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"code" sender:self];
[pref setBool:YES forKey:@"islogin"];
```

i didn't add synchornize because in my device it is working perfectly,now i add synchronize and i am waiting the results.

Comment: Please post the code you use to save the value in the user defaults, that's where your issue will be.

Comment: [pref setObject:[response valueForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"user_id"];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"code" sender:self];
            [pref setBool:YES forKey:@"islogin"];


i didn't add synchornize because in my device it is working perfectly,now i add synchronize and i am waiting the results..

Comment: Put code in your question, not comments.

Comment: NSLog just prior to setting, just after setting and just after retrieving.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to save the NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"islogin"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: This is only needed if you kill the app before the user defaults are automatically saved.

Comment: The val;ue inthe app is always up-to-date, synchronization only applies to saving to disk. From Apple docs: "'Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk." and "Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes."